# how to add images on gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

In this following gridview `image.png` images are taken from the `drawable` folder.Now I want the images from the photo gallery or captured camera image add dynamically in this grid.How to do?

Any example code?

HelloGridView class:

```
package com.example.HelloGridView; 

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 

public class HelloGridView extends Activity { 
/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview); 
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); 

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) { 
            Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        } 
    }); 
    }
```

ImageAdapter class:

```
package com.example.HelloGridView; 

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
private Context mContext; 

public ImageAdapter(Context c) { 
mContext = c; 
} 

public int getCount() { 
return mThumbIds.length; 
} 

public Object getItem(int position) { 
return null; 
} 

public long getItemId(int position) { 
return 0; 
} 

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
ImageView imageView; 
if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes 
    imageView = new ImageView(mContext); 
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85)); 
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP); 
    imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8); 
} else { 
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView; 
} 

imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]); 
return imageView; 
} 

// references to our images 
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5, 
R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7, 
R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1, 
R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3, 
R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5, 
R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7, 
R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1, 
R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3, 
R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5, 
R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7 
};
```

Comment: Better you check this: http://goo.gl/W2Cfp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put images in the folder[images ] in SD card

```
public class ChannelImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;
    File[] images;
    File[] files;
    public ChannelImageAdapter(Context c, int folderID) {
        mContext = c;

        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images");
        files = dir.listFiles();
        images = files[folderID].listFiles();

    }
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return images[position].getAbsolutePath();
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public String getAlbumName(int folderID) {
        return files[folderID].getName();
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView imageView;
        //Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory
        //      .decodeFile(images[position].getAbsolutePath());
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 10, 5, 10);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.decode(images[position].getAbsoluteFile()));
        return imageView;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ChannelImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;
    File[] images;
    File[] files;
    public ChannelImageAdapter(Context c, int folderID) {
        mContext = c;

        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images");
        files = dir.listFiles();
        images = files[folderID].listFiles();

    }
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return images[position].getAbsolutePath();
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public String getAlbumName(int folderID) {
        return files[folderID].getName();
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 10, 5, 10);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.decode(images[position].getAbsoluteFile()));
        return imageView;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to explain how and why this code works, so that all users can learn from it.