# how to open a folder and its contents on Click of a button in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Could you please let me know how to open a folder and its contents in android on click of a button.
Looking forward to the reply.

thanks.

Comment: which folder are you talking about?

Comment: Opening an Image Gallery to show all the image files.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to open gallery and pick any image from gallery?

Comment: @PareshMayani absolutely... I want to open gallery on a click of a button and pick image from a gallery...

Comment: @PareshMayani no I am not not seeing from that point, all I want is to open an Image Gallery which lists folders having images and the user clicks on the folder to open and then chooses an image and like this the user can can select three pictures.

Comment: @PareshMayani like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458752/get-the-path-of-a-gallery-folder-in-android?s=43e1a6cc-b7fa-4daf-8b7d-30e8a24288cc#new-answer
so next after browsing image folders an user can pick up a image

Answer (score 1):

If you want start gallery you need just start activity with special intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
photoUri = getPhotoUri(activity);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, activity.getText(R.string.select_camera_app)), ACTIVITY_FOTO);
```

`photoUri` is used in `onActivityResult()` later to get selected picture.

Comment: Can you please let me know what is activity in your code and how would you declare an activity, normally we call as 
'public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), abc.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);'

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write this `on onclick listener`
of a btn

```
 File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images");
 files = dir.listFiles();//list files with in the folder
```

Comment: but how to show images in a Image Gallery...It should tile wise list all the images... opening upon on a image folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515830/how-to-add-images-on-gridview/8515951#8515951